# How do you stop piracy of Windows Phone 7 applications?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Given the recent hack on Preemptive's CEO's Windows Phone 7 App, what do other developers do to limit their application's chances of being ripped off?

http://apps-are-people-too.blogspot.com/2012/01/hoisted-by-my-own-petard-or-why-my-app_09.html

I am not just looking for "a solution" as nearly all of them will have flaws, but instead one that balances the wire between "slows down all the code your put through it" and "isn't really that effective in practice"

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The app you mention hasn't been hacked. Only the media has been extracted and copied into a new app.

The only (semi)-reliable way to protect against this is to stream your media on-demand, after the user has authenticated. Fingerprint the media using one of the many cryptography/steganography methods out there with unique user ID signature. This way, if/when your media is eventually ripped off, you have at least some chance of identifying the user whose copy the media was ripped from. (Not that this is going to help you much, if you are sticking to only legal actions. Which I strongly recommend.)

Reality is - there is no way you can protect content using technology. The only thing you can do is follow up the legal procedures set by the app store.

Comment: thanks - i was actually just using that as an intro to my question. do you have any anti-piracy techniques that you use in your apps?

Comment: Nope, nothing special. Than again, my apps are free anyway, so no point in pirating them. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let each app download an ID and verifiy it against paid ones. Make this verification happen every so often, not all the time or else it wouldn't work without internet. Also make sure that the user can't use the app unless they are verified within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but my question is: How do you know if a device ID has paid? Where do you get this information from the Windows Phone Marketplace?

Answer (score 1):

See this anti-piracy code, it works 100% with our apps too!!!
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/PROTECT-YOUR-Windows-Phone-APP-AGAINST--casual--PIRACY

Comment: David, it helps in some veeery easy cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to use is MTIKS WP7 SDK. http://us2.campaign-archive1.com/?u=ef88cf9415282e762a33f866c&id=6cf2a86fb3 Here they state they can track piracy.

My opinion is currently using any  anti-piracy check is bit stupid, because of current store model and certification process.